# Decorated and not-movable stage in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I want to create a decorated stage in JavaFx and it will be not movable too. I am creating this stage from another controller class. I am able to create and show the stage but it is moving freely. How can I create this? Help and suggestions are highly appreciated. I am pasting the method for opening new stage.

```
private void addReceiver() {

    Parent receivercvDetailsparent;

    try {
        receivercvDetailsparent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/project/fxml/ReceiverDetails.fxml"));
        Stage stageReceiver = new Stage();
        stageReceiver.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stageReceiver.setTitle("AppName v2.0.0");
        stageReceiver.setScene(new Scene(receivercvDetailsparent));
        stageReceiver.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        stageReceiver.setResizable(false);
        stageReceiver.getIcons().add(new Image("/com/project/images/logo.png"));
        stageReceiver.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A stage is a window usually so the only way to sort of fake it's immovability is to make it undecorated

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

It only prevents window dragging automatically, but I'm afraid it is the only thing you can do

Comment: I need to make the stage "StageStyle.DECORATED", otherwise min,max,close options will be removed from the window.

Comment: You can emulate them yourself, I think. Here is good example of how it was done in ControlsFX library https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/cc955ea2b309a4a55e06253f4ac56e94d0d7fa6e/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/dialog/FXDialog.java?at=8.0-final&fileviewer=file-view-default